# C++: Cloud computing library: is there such a library where I don't need to write much network stuff?

Tags: c++, networking, cloud

I want my server app to be able to send data to be processed by a bunch of various clients, and then have the processed data returned to the server.

Ideally, I'd have some call like `some_process = send_to_client_for_calculating(connection, data)`

I just need to be able to send a bunch of data to a client, tell the client what to do (preferably in the same message, which can be done with an array [command, data]), and then return the data...

I'm breaking up pieces of a neural network (tis very large), and then assembling them all later.

If I need to be clearer, let me know how.

Comment: This depends highly on how you intend to program it. There's Boost.Asio, MPI, remote procedure calls, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm shocked no one has thrown it out there... how about [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html).

Comment: +1 it is the de-facto networking library for C++ applications at any scale.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you have a look at using [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/)?  It's a Java JMS server, but it has C++ bindings, and does what you want with a minimum of writing networking code.  You basically just subscribe to messages, and send responses back.  The MQ server takes care of dispatch and message persistence for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/), a fast working queue. I don't know if it fits your purposes. There is a [client library](http://github.com/bergundy/libbeanstalkclient/) written in C, which you should be able to use from C++.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html), which implements SOAP in C++, including networking.